# Ionic 4 - ion-button does not style my Ionic button

Tags: angularjs, ionic4

I just want my button to look like Ionic buttons do.

The following image is from Ionic 4 documentation:

[image]

The following image is when I[image] apply ionic button to my project:

In my google searches solutions suggested to include 
`IonicModule` into **component.module.ts** and I already done this method but it is still not working.

By the way I am working on the Ionic tabs template.

Answer (score 0):

With Ionic 4, you now need to use ion-button. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Answer (score -3):

i just solve this problem by using  tag instead of  tag

Comment: please update your answer as it is clearly missing some information